# NoSuchMethodError with spring ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.clearMetadataCache and multi module maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-3

I get this log when I run webapp under tomcat 7.0.63:

> [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.clearMetadataCache()V
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:673)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)

This webapp works out fine when I deploy it simply exporting war with classical option in eclipse.
But when I build with maven in a multi module fashion. I got above errors  on execution.
Could anyone give me some hint or direction in order to solve this issue?

Spring version in use is 4.2.0.RELEASE.

I don't use Spring Boot.

Comment: can you show us your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Sure. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bcf36372baefeec00434d254f959d77d

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added the spring-web dependency in the `POM.xml` as the dependencies are required while building a MAVEN project. Hope you solve it.

Comment: Yes, I've added that dependency:
org.springframework: spring-web: 4.2.0.RELEASE